# Multiline errorformat in vim

Tags: vim, multiline, errorformat

I'm trying to match on C error messages like this:

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/project/swbuild45/ethanl/swfeature_int/pkt'
...
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c: In function 'bfd_delete_constituent_session':
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3654: error: 'bfd_ses' undeclared (first use in this function)
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3654: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3654: error: for each function it appears in.)
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3654: error: expected ';' before 'sion_cst'
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3663: error: 'dbl_dequ' undeclared (first use in this function)
sw/se/xc/bsd/routing/rib/src/rib_bfd_thrd.c:3663: error: expected ';' before 'eue'
...
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/project/swbuild45/ethanl/swfeature_int/pkt'
```

So far I came up with this:

```
errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m,%Dgmake[%\\d%\\*]:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',%Xgmake[%\\d%\\*]:\ Leaving\ directory%s
```

It opens the file and puts me to the first error, but I have to type `:cn` four times to get to the second error. I've tried to setup multiline errors, but so far my error string doesn't work:

```
errorformat=%-Z%f:\ %s,%C%f:%l:\ %m,%A%f:\ %m,%Dgmake[%\\d%\\*]:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',%Xgmake[%\\d%\\*]:\ Leaving\ directory%s
```

Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It may help to open the quickfix window

```
:copen
```

You can then visually navigate through your error list and type <enter> on the error you are interested in to jump directly to the line in question.

Also see

```
:help quickfix
```

Comment: That helps, but it is not really what I want to achieve :-( Anyway, I'm not quite sure if it can be achieved at all.

Answer (score 5):

Well, certainly multiline error format is a pain in the ass, so you need a method to refine your [errorformat](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat) quickly.

1. redirect your compilation output to a file or a vim buffer (so you can play with it if neccesary)

   ```
   $ make &> <your-error-file>
   ```
2. goto vim, open quickfix window

   ```
   :copen
   ```
3. start your refine loop

   ```
   :set errorformat=<whatever>
   :caddf <your-error-file>
   :cex []
   :set errorformat=<whatever>
   :caddf <your-error-file>
   ...
   ```

explaining:

1. set an error format
2. read your error file. You can replace that with

   ```
   :read <your-error-file>
   :caddbuffer
   ```

> That ease to change your input, to detect different errors

If results are not the expected:

3. clean quickfix window

   ```
   :cex []
   ```

> That command load an empty list to quickfix window

For your question

```
:set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %trror:\ %m,%Dgmake[%*\\d]:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',%Xgmake[%*\\d]:\ Leaving\ directory\ `%f',%-G%.%#
```

should be enough